# TypeError: Cannot read property 'experience' of null (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am student and learning ReactJS building a Web aplication and I am having problem with that error.

```
router.post('/experience', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateExperienceInput(req.body);

//Check Validation
if (!isValid) {
    //Return any errors with 400 status
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
}

Profile.findOne({ user: req.user_id })
    .then(profile => {
        const newExp = {
            title: req.body.title,
            company: req.body.company,
        }
        //Add to experience array
        //There is the error generated
        profile.experience.unshift(newExp);
        profile.save().then(profile => res.json(profile));
    })
});
```

here is profile model where experience array is declared

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
},
handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
},
experience: [
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
    }
],
});
```

and thats the error I got

```
(node:14580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'experience' of null
at C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\LinkedIn\routes\api\profile.js:180:21
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I am using Visual Studio Code
on Windows 10 Pro
And testing app using Postman Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profile.experience.unshift(newExp)` this line causes the error (unless it is caused by the code you didn't post).

Possible cause is that your `findOne` did not actually "findOne" and returned undefined.

You could add an `if`

```
Profile.findOne({ user: req.user_id })
    .then(profile => {
        if (!profile) return
        const newExp = {
            title: req.body.title,
            company: req.body.company,
        }
        //Add to experience array
        //There is the error generated
        profile.experience.unshift(newExp);
        profile.save().then(profile => res.json(profile));
    })
});
```

Or any equivalent code.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `profile` is null. You need to pass the object to the `resolve` method in the Promise definition, `findOne`, (not shown above). Example:

```js
let findOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let resolveParam = { experience: [] };
  setTimeout(() => resolve(resolveParam), 1000);
});
findOne.then(
  profile => console.log(profile)
);
```